# Custom Function to download & unzip file and extract csv data in Google Sheet App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a custom function to download a ZIP file(csv) from website. Data set available for downloading is of multiple symbols (2200 rows) with 12 columns.
1 - Objective is to fetch a zip file with customized URL(having date suffix) and extract data.
2 - Run Filter / query to get data for selected attribute's value of selected date and symbol (as inputs).
3 - Output cell gives value for selected - URLs, Date, Attribute (for selecting a Column) and Symbol.
Sharing Sheet pl. checkout for betterunderstanding.
Sheet link is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e2qzU3RwYVILAdwEKNw-kbEICYGcNh5P0PfhOprFcgw/edit?usp=sharing

Till now Script used gets and unzip file in a 'Temp' sheet. Need further help and guidance to move further from here.
Code is as follows -
''''

```
/** 
 * Import csv file of a date
 * 
 * @param {URL} input for custom date file name to be downloaded
 * @param {symbol} Data for this symbol is to be extracted
 * @param {date} Data for this date is to be extracted
 * @param {attribute} Data  for this attribute is to be extracted
 * @ return data array of listed symbols for a range of listed dates of desired attributes
 * @ customfunction
 */

function importbhav(url,symbol,date,attribute) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Temp') ;  // Temp location for unzipping csv file
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1') ;  // Final location for data reqd. in desired format (i.e. date-wise , symbol-wise of selected attributes )
  
  var Cell_A = s1.getActiveRange().getValue(); // URL reference which is date linked
  var Cell_B = s1.getActiveRange('$B$5:$B').getValue(); // symbol 
  var Cell_C = s1.getActiveRange('$D$4:$KO$4').getValue(); // date
  var Cell_D = s1.getActiveRange('G1').getValue(); // date
  var url = Cell_A  ;
  var symbol = Cell_B  ;
  var date = Cell_C ;
  var Attribute = Cell_D

  // attribute list
  var Attribute = [Dattributes_1,Dattributes_2,Dattributes_3,Dattributes_4,Dattributes_5,Dattributes_6,Dattributes_7,Dattributes_8,Dattributes_8,Dattributes_9]  ;
  var Dattributes_1="SYMBOL"  ;
  var Dattributes_2="SERIES"  ;
  var Dattributes_3="OPEN" ;
  var Dattributes_4="HIGH" ;
  var Dattributes_5="LOW" ;
  var Dattributes_6="CLOSE" ;
  var Dattributes_7="LAST" ;
  var Dattributes_8="TOTTRDVAL" ;
  var Dattributes_9="TOTALTRADES" ;

  //  downloading + unzipping file 
  var zipblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob(); 
  var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob); 
  var unzipstr=unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(unzipstr);

  ss.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).clearContent().setValues(csv);

  // return input

}
```

;
''''

Comment: Can you summarize what exactly you are trying to achieve as the enxt goal? You are at the point where you already have your data as csv and now would to filter your data to return only the one matching your criteria? What exactly is the difficulty you encounter when trying to do so? Are you looking for advice on a method which would allow you to filter data?

Comment: @ ziganotschka - The File which is to be downloaded is available for single date (new file is reqd for every date change). I want this data to build a database of stock symbols with historical data (e.g. Open, High, Low, Close, Qty etc.). for that, the idea of custom Function came, that can fetch a particular value of attribute(Open, Close etc.) matching to the downloaded file's column in a cell (of Sheet1) wrt to a stock symbol, (all input reqd. references to be in respective cells.).

Comment: I am using a 'TEMP' Sheet to download the file. Want to add query function, to fetch the reqd. data in Sheet1. And 'TEMP' Sheet is only being used to check the function's workability. Aiming to customize and get output without any need for this 'TEMP' sheet.

Comment: Pl. Note that 'Temp' sheet is source. And 'Sheet1' is database table. Temp sheet gets data for 1 day only. Whereas database I m trying to build is for 100 + days. Based on time efficiency other work arounds suggestion are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

I believe what you are asking for is, if you place the formula in any cell it will look up that column to row 5 for the date and along that row in column B for the symbol.  Here as an example of how to do that.  I leave the search of the url csv to you.

You simply type `=test()` in any cell and the results are displayed in that cell.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let date = sheet.getRange(4,cell.getColumn()).getValue();  // date
    let symbol = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),2).getValue();  // symbol
    let option = sheet.getRange(1,7).getValue(); // option
    return date.toString()+","+symbol+","+option;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange())